# ASP.NET 5 Beta 7 - Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr missing with GIT deploy

Tags: git, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core

If I create a new ASP.NET v5 application in VS2015 and publish it to azure, it works fine.  But when I setup continuous deployment with my GIT repository I get this error viewing the page after the deployment:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What's the trick to getting this setup in the web app with a GIT deploy?

Comment: How do you publish? Do you invoke `dnu publish`? If yes, do you pass `--runtime`?

Comment: The thing is, I'm not publishing this.  I'm using Azure Continuous Deployment with GIT. I don't see how to change the runtime when doing that. The instructions don't seem to be complete at the ASP.net website.

Comment: Do you get any deployment errors / log information? Maybe you're missing Nuget package sources in NuGet.config - I had this problem - it ran on local machine but did not work on Azure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is related to the version of DNX running on your Azure web app.I had a similar issue: Taking a standard ASP.NET 5 Web API app generated by yeoman, adding this project with no modifications to git and then using this repo as the source for Continuous deployment in Azure results in the same error you are experiencing.

Azure uses kudu to manage git deploys, and it appears the version of DNX used by default is currently **beta6** ([detail here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/commit/b31e6aee952cf983c813ebb6e131adfb0e886c01)). Following the first commit, navigating to the site\approot\runtimes folder in the kudu debug console ([more info here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console)) shows the runtime as dnx-CLR-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6.

Adding a global.json file into the project root with the following:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta7"
  }
}
```

...committing to git and then redeploying appears to resolve this particular error, updating the runtime to dnx-CLR-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer!